# For object with multiple arrays, return array based on checking two values inside the same array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering

I am trying to sort multiple arrays based on codes inside, I was able to do it based on single code, but I am not able to sort based on multiple code inside the same array

I am trying to do it with filter and find in javascript

my mock Json is

```
response: 
[ 
{   id: 1, 
    moreDetails: [ 
          { code: '24', value: some}, 
          { code: '25', value: some}, 
          { code: '04', value: some}], 
    days: 10}
{   id: 2, 
    moreDetails: [ 
          { code: '24', value: some}, 
          { code: '04', value: some}], 
     days: 10}
{   id: 3, 
    moreDetails: [
          { code: '24', value: some},
          { code: '25', value: some}],
      days: 10}
{   id: 4, 
    moreDetails: [ 
          { code: '24', value: some},
          { code: '25', value: some}, 
          { code: '04', value: some}], 
      days: 10}
{   id: 5, 
    moreDetails: [ 
          { code: '25', value: some}, 
          { code: '04', value: some}], 
      days: 10}
```

I tried this

```
const sorttwofive = response.filter(c=> c.moreDetails.find(s => s.code === '25'));
const sorttwofour = response.filter(c=> c.moreDetails.find(s => s.code === '24'));
const sortfour = response.filter(c=> c.moreDetails.find(s => s.code === '04'));
```

these are working fine and getting exact output, when I wanted to do filter the response based on two codes. I am getting empty object.
I tried doing this,

```
const const sorttwofiveandfour = response.filter(c=> c.moreDetails.find(s => s.code === '25' && s.code === '24'));
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your expected output? `'25' !== '24'`, so your current code will never find anything (unless `.lob` is an impure getter, or something like that)

Comment: I need to sort the array when we have both codes '25' and '24' in the response. 
(my bad its not .lob its .code)

Comment: @Eddie Nope, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `.filter` by whether an array of `['24', '25']` pass an `every` test, where that test `.find`s a matching code in the `moreDetails`:

```js
const some = 'some';
const response = [{
    id: 1,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '25',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '25',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '25',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '25',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  }
];

const objsWhichContainCode24And25 = response.filter(
  obj => ['24', '25'].every(
    codeToFind => obj.moreDetails.find(s => s.code === codeToFind)
  )
);
console.log(objsWhichContainCode24And25);
```

For `O(N)` complexity instead of `O(N^2)` complexity, construct a Set of the codes in `moreDetail` in advance:

```js
const some = 'some';
const response = [{
    id: 1,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '25',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '25',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '24',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '25',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    moreDetails: [{
        code: '25',
        value: some
      },
      {
        code: '04',
        value: some
      }
    ],
    days: 10
  }
];

const objsWhichContainCode24And25 = response.filter(
  obj => {
    const codes = new Set(obj.moreDetails.map(({ code }) => code));
    return ['24', '25'].every(code => codes.has(code));
  }
);
console.log(objsWhichContainCode24And25);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the values that have the both codes 24 and 25 you should try the following.

```
const sorttwofiveandfour = response.filter(c=> c.moreDetails.find(s => s.code === '25') && c.moreDetails.find(s => s.code ==='24'));
```